# How to set a specific rating on RatingBar in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ratingbar

I'm trying to write an Espresso test that tests a RatingBar selection. How can I set a specific rating using Espresso? I only see `click()`, which always sets the middle rating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a custom subclass of ViewAction that calls setRating on the view, then pass an instance of your custom view action to the perform() method.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer helped me write the following custom ViewAction:

```
public final class SetRating implements ViewAction {

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        Matcher <View> isRatingBarConstraint = ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(RatingBar.class);
        return isRatingBarConstraint;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Custom view action to set rating.";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view;
        ratingBar.setRating(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What the isAssignableFrom does here?

Comment: @karate you can find it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html

Comment: @appoli Thanks for the answer, it would make clear if you would change it to ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(RatingBar.class)

Comment: Works out of the box! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than calling `setRating` in a custom View action, which sets the rating programmatically, you can also send a tap event to the correct part of the view.

This means that you can use the `boolean fromUser` parameter in your production code, avoiding the need to set the rating bar change listener to null prior to setting the rating:

```
ratingBar.setRating(viewModel.rating());
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            viewModel.actions().onRate(rating);
        }
    }
});
```

---

The following action was enough for me, since my rating bar is set in 0.5 steps and has 5 stars in total:

```
RateableMovieViewModel viewModel = viewModel(userActions).build();
rateableMovieViewHolder.bind(viewModel);

onView(withId(R.id.item_rateable_rating)).perform(setRating(4.5f));

verify(userActions).onRate(4.5f);
```

---

```
private static ViewAction setRating(final float rating) {
    if (rating % 0.5 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rating must be multiple of 0.5f");
    }

    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(RatingBar.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Set rating on RatingBar in 0.5f increments";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            GeneralClickAction viewAction = new GeneralClickAction(
                    Tap.SINGLE,
                    new CoordinatesProvider() {
                        @Override
                        public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
                            int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
                            v.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
                            int screenX = locationOnScreen[0];
                            int screenY = locationOnScreen[1];
                            int numStars = ((RatingBar) view).getNumStars();
                            float widthPerStar = 1f * view.getWidth() / numStars;
                            float percent = rating / numStars;
                            float x = screenX + view.getWidth() * percent;
                            float y = screenY + view.getHeight() * 0.5f;
                            return new float[]{x - widthPerStar * 0.5f, y};
                        }
                    },
                    Press.FINGER,
                    InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN,
                    MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY
            );
            viewAction.perform(uiController, view);
        }
    };
}
```